# GeckoFX and C# ! Error on clicking on a button to delete a file

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have 2 problems with combining GeckoFX and C#.

1.When i clicks on a button,my application is going to open a OpenFileDialog(generated by C# code) to change src attribute of a img tag.I use a contextmenu for this img to do that. My problem is if i click once on button which to open the OpenFileDialog after that i click on img (without contextmenu) the OpenFileDialog opens again.

2.When i choose new image for this img,i can't delete old file(using C# code)
Here is my code

[HTML and Javascript code]

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_image).bind('contextmenu',function(){
        $('#contextmenu_image').css({top: e.pageY+'px',left: e.pageX+'px'}).show();
    });

});
</script>
<div class="div_image" style="position: absolute; top: '20px;left:'20px;"><img id="img123" class="image" src="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"/></div>
<ul class="contextmenu" id="contextmenu_image" style="width: 100px; display: none;">
    <li class="properties">Properties</li>
    <li class="del">Delete</li>
    <button id="choose_image">Choose image</button> 
</ul>
```

[C# code]

```c#
private void ChooseImage()
    {
        if (geckoWebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.GetAttribute("id") == "choose_image")
        {

            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter =
                "Image (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.JPEG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.JPEG|" +
                "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            open.Title = "Choose an image";

            DialogResult result = open.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string srcFile = open.FileName;
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(srcFile);
                string fileExtent = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(srcFile);
                string desDir = Application.StartupPath + "\\test\\images\\";
                Random r = new Random();
                string newFileName = "i_";
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    newFileName += Convert.ToString(r.Next(0, 9));
                }
                newFileName += fileExtent;
                System.IO.File.Copy(srcFile, desDir + newFileName);
                //Find old image
                string old_image = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("img123").GetAttribute("src");
                geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("img123").SetAttribute("src", "images/" + newFileName);
                 if (old_image != "")

                    System.IO.File.Delete(desDir + old_image);//Delete old file,but unable



            }
        }
    }
 private void geckoWebBrowser1_DomClick(object sender, GeckoDomEventArgs e)
    {
        ChooseImage();
    }
```

Sorry because of my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, I recommend changing how you wire up the click event:

browser.OnBrowserClick += new System.EventHandler(OnBrowserClick);

Then, you'll get an argument telling you what was clicked:

```
private void OnBrowserClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ge = e as GeckoDomEventArgs;
    if (ge.Target.ClassName =="choose_image")
    {
       //Handle the click...
```

For your second problem, I thought perhaps the browser was holding on to the file, but in my experiments, it does not. I recommend you make sure the file is really there:

```
var oldPath = Path.Combine(desDir);
if(File.Exists(oldPath))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(oldPath);
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        //do something about not being able to delete the file yet
    }
}
```

If you'd like to look at some open-source code that does a lot of these kinds of things with geckofx, see my [Bloom project](http://projects.palaso.org/projects/bloom), particularly EditingView.cs and Browser.cs.

Comment: Thank a lot!I tried to use this code at bottom of function
    
         geckoWebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.Blur();

And for second error,i mistake at path.Hum!Thank a again! Iam going to try your code!